# what's the best way to make this layout fluid?

Tags: html, css

I want to know, what's the best structure to make this layout with pure CSS. The arrow can be an image.

http://www.labonedesign.com.br/layout_2012.png

I need a fluid layout, but I don't know how to make this.

The pink is the menu container and the brown is my content container.

I have tried this, but on small resolution this does not work:

```
 <body>

    <div class="glob">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="wrap_lateral">
            <div class="lateral">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="conteudo">

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>  


 </body>
```

CSS:

```
body {position:absolute; min-width:100%; min-height:700px; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
.glob {position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
.main {margin:0px auto 0 auto; width:100% z-index:2; height:100%;}


.wrap_lateral{
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#FFCC00 url(../img/seta.png) 330px center no-repeat;
}

.lateral{
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:330px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#ff0066;
}

.conteudo{
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
    background:#CC0000;
}
```

PS.: I did this on photoshop :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a simplified example that seems to fit the image and description you provided. Is this what you're looking for?

**HTML**

```
<nav></nav>
<div></div>
<section></section>
```

**CSS**

```
nav { /* left bar */
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
}
div { /* CSS triangle */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 200px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid red;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
}
section { /* box */
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 220px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 220px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 220px);
    top: 50%;
    top: calc(50% - 80px);
    top: -webkit-calc(50% - 80px);
    top: -moz-calc(50% - 80px);
    left: 220px;
    background: brown;
}
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AF9zp/1/)**

It uses a CSS triangle instead of an image. You may need to make some adjustments for it to fit your specific case, since what you have now does not seem to have any content.

**Edit:**

The tags used above are from the new HTML5 specification and will not work for older browsers. You can fix this by replacing the `nav` and `section` tags with `div`.

Separate stylesheets can be made to target only IE or specific versions of IE as well.

*IE Only:*

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

*IE 7 Only:*

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

*IE version less than 9:*

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ielt9.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar it will still work (notice the `width: 100%` before the calculations), but just appear differently in lower version IE browsers. With the correct `DOCTYPE`, this typically will not be an issue unless the user is in a situation where they are not permitted to use the latest browsers or versions of IE (typically seen in the government or large corporations). If the OP wishes, he/she can create separate CSS files for IE.

Comment: I meant the `calc` and CSS Triangle which you mentioned. +1 for you! :)

Comment: Can you please check http://i.imgur.com/u6C1p.png. It was taken in IE 7. May be the OP was looking in IE 7? Not sure...

Comment: @PraveenKumar sorry, you were right before when saying it won't work with lower versions of IE. I was focusing on the `calc`, but forgot that I was also using `nav` and `section`, which are part of the new HTML5 specifications. If you replace those with `div` elements then the left bar and box will appear.

Comment: yeah.. i see that, another way, is use  `<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
< ![endif]-->`  this create HTML5 tags on IE.

Comment: @Zhihao, one question. The css triangule, starts ate 50% of top. but, this position is not the exactly middle of the "arrow", there's a way to perfect center this?

Comment: guys, i have a problem. on IE8 this make me a horizontal scrollbar. i have updated the Fiddle with `div` tags: http://jsfiddle.net/AF9zp/2/ pls, open on IE and you see the problem

Comment: @Preston about the CSS triangle issue, you can get it perfectly in the middle using the `calc` I used for the other elements. Something like `top: calc(50% - 10px);`.

Comment: @Preston About the IE8 issue, I don't have access to IE at the moment, but you will need to use JavaScript. There is a scrollbar because IE8 does not support `calc`, which is from CSS3 (IE8 only supports up to CSS2). Since the width cannot be calculated, it defaults to `width: 100%`, which is the width of the window. To get the elements both perfectly in the middle AND fluid, you will need to use JS to calculate the width of the window and resize the width of the box whenever the user changes the window size. Basically, use JS to set the width to window width, minus width of nav and triangle.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use this *CSS* for your work:

```
.lateral img {position: absolute; top: 42.5%; right: -50px; width: 100px;}
```

And check out this **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/QhUVA/

Comment: hum... but with this, i'm able to insert some content inside `.lateral` ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar perhaps I am misunderstanding the question, but this answer seems to only give a possible solution to the arrow positioning, and does not actually address the layout the OP asked for. Is there something I am missing, since this answer has gotten so many upvotes> (I don't mean to be rude, just asking for clarification)

Comment: @Zhihao What you have given is also right. I have upvoted your answer. :)